# Issues reading a text file in the same folder as the JAR program

Tags: java, file, text, jar

I have a text file in the same location as my .jar program:

Main Folder:

|_ myJar.jar

|_ myText.txt

When I run the .jar file I would like it to read the contents of myText.txt, however with the path set as `String fileName = "./Paths.txt";` it still doesn't read the file.  I believe it's trying to read the Paths.txt file from inside the jar.

I tried other solutions, none seem to tell the program to read the Paths.txt file from outside of the jar file, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Code:

```
public static void readFile() { 

    String fileName = "./Paths.txt"; 
    BufferedReader br; 
    String line; 
    //Attempts to read fileName
    try { 
        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(fileName)));
        try { 
            // Starts reading the file and adding values to linked hashmap
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) { 
                String[] lineSplit1 = line.split("#"); 
                String lineKey = lineSplit1[0]; 
                String lineValue = lineSplit1[1]; 
                hm.put(lineKey, lineValue);
            }
        } catch(Exception e3) { 
            errorMessage("Error when trying to read the file and add "
                    + "the values to a hashmap"); 
        }
        //Attempts to close fileName
        try {
            br.close();
        } catch(IOException e1 ) { 
            System.out.println("Messed up while trying to close buffered reader"); 
            System.out.println(e1); 
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) { 
        errorMessage("The file " + fileName + " does not exist" 
                 + "\nI have created the file for you."); 
        try {  
            PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(fileName, "UTF-8");
            writer.println("");
            writer.close();
        } catch(Exception e2) { 
            errorMessage("Error while trying to create " + fileName);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use either `System.getProperty("user.dir")` or `new File(".")` and print out the result to the console to make sure that the working directory is the same place you expect it to be...You can also use `File#exits` to test to see if the exists or not, which can help..

Answer (score 0):

I suppose, you can get a full path to your file, just need to initialize it, via your Class, which should be packaged in myJar.jar. Just change YourClass in the example to some real Class from your jar.

```
public static void readFile() { 
  File file = new File(YourClass.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getFile());        
  String fileName = file.getParent() + File.separator + "Paths.txt";
...
```